# ImageTTFText unicode problem

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I write non-English characters to an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7426685/how-can-i-write-non-english-characters-to-an-image)

I have followed both solutions listed here:

[PHP function imagettftext() and unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198007/php-function-imagettftext-and-unicode#201787)

but none of them worked. I used Arabic letters to be drawn into the image but they still crashed, here is the screenshot:

http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2559/5757740544_708c5ff118.jpg

I tried many ways possible to convert $text into a readable encoding, but nothing worked !
is there a possible solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 2):

quote from [php.net](https://www.php.net/)

> If a character is used in the string
> which is not supported by the font, a
> hollow rectangle will replace the
> character.

the seventh parameter is the font file ... try using different font

Comment: your answer has partially solved the problem, but the resulting text is in discrete Arabic characters not continuous as it should be, do you have any clue about that, screenshot of this result: http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2801/5757934474_0606f65599.jpg

Comment: @JaHelia what do you mean by discrete and on the screenshot looks quite well I think :)

Comment: in Arabic language (unlike many other languages) characters are connected together (not letter by letter like english)

Comment: @JaHelia isn't it the same if you use the same font in some text editor

Comment: nope .. look at this screenshot to clarify things: http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3512/5758642698_3e8ee79ee8_m.jpg  this screenshot contains the right Arabic (connected) characters