# PHP Image Create with UTF-8 Character

Tags: php, utf-8

When I create an image with PHP, it does not display UTF-8 characters properly.

```
$imgPath = 'uplatnica1.jpg';
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgPath);
$color = imagecolorallocate($image, 000, 000, 000);

$string = "šđčćž";
$x = 70;
$y = 200;

$fontSize = 3;

imagestring($image, $fontSize, $x, $y, $string, $color);
imagejpeg($image, 'qwe.jpg');
```

**How can I solve this problem?**

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458317/working-with-gd-imagettftext-and-utf-8-characters

Comment: Maybe your problem is in the font you are using; In some post I found that you must have both the GD library and the FreeType library installed in the server.

Answer (score 0):

It's always good to [read documentation prior asking](http://php.net/imagestring)

> font
>
> Can be 1, 2, ***3***, 4, 5 for built-in fonts ***in latin2 encoding*** (where
>   higher numbers corresponding  to larger fonts) or any of your own font
>   identifiers registered with imageloadfont().

and UTF8 is not subset of latin2

Answer (score 0):

You could check out [imagettftext](http://php.net/imagettftext).

Your code will become:

```
$imgPath = 'uplatnica1.jpg';
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgPath);
$color = imagecolorallocate($image, 000, 000, 000);

$string = "šđčćž";
$x = 70;
$y = 200;

$fontSize = 3;
$fontFile = 'verdana.ttf'; // This file must reside on your system

imagettftext($image, $fontSize, 0, $x, $y, $color, $fontFile, $string);
imagejpeg($image, 'qwe.jpg');
```

Don't forget that your `$fontFile` must exist on the server and be accessible by the code.

Comment: Warning: imagettftext() [function.imagettftext]: Invalid font filename in C:\xampp\htdocs\prirucnici-akcija\slika2.php on line 13

Comment: Have you placed `verdana.ttf` in the same directory as the script?

Comment: Warning: imagettftext() [function.imagettftext]: any2eucjp(): something happen in C:\xampp\htdocs\prirucnici-akcija\slika2.php on line 13

Comment: Have you read the documentation? I may have missed something. Just double check that `verdana.ttf` is in the **same** directory as this script.