# How to correctly show accents or special characters (ñ) in php-gd?

Tags: php, php-gd

How to correctly show accents or special characters `(ñ)` in php-gd?

Currently used code:

```
$TXT_Name = mb_strtoupper('á é í ó ú ñ'), 'UTF-8');
imagettftext($CANVAS, 20, 0, 10, 20, $color, $FONT, $TXT_Name);
```

Comment: How to correct them? I wasn't aware there was anything wrong with them.

Comment: You need to use a font that supports UTF-8

Comment: Sorry, I mean how to display it properly. In my case the accents are not displayed. The source is "Segoe UI" and out of php-gd shows the accents correctly.