# language readability for add text to image in php

Tags: php, netbeans-8

I add text to image in php using  the following code:

```
    $font_path = 'assets/bend/fonts/Arial.ttf';
    $text = 'Молдавия';
    imagettftext($stars, 40, 0, 150, 200, $white, $font_path, $text); 
    imagejpeg($stars, 'images/newtes1.jpg');
```

However, it fails to read non latin letters such as russian for example. It shows symbols like squares. I have changed different fonts which work otherwise, but when i want to add to the image it doesnt. I work with netbeans if it matters. Thanks in advance.

Comment: check this post i think it covers you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458317/working-with-gd-imagettftext-and-utf-8-characters

Comment: My understanding is that netbeans is more forgiving for errors. So a smal mistake is corrected in netbeans php server, but on web you get an error. I can't see what the problem is but this is my understanding of netbeans

Comment: Boys thanks a lot. it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Try this font:
[Arimo-Arial-Font](http://www.1001fonts.com/arimo-font.html?text=%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8F)

The code below works for me:

```
<?php
  $jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('test.jpg');
  $text = 'Молдавия'; //Or any other text
  $font_path = "Arimo-Regular.ttf"; //Or any other font
  $white = imagecolorallocate($jpg_image, 255, 255, 255);
  imagettftext($jpg_image, 40, 0, 150, 200, $white, $font_path, $text); 
  imagejpeg($jpg_image, 'test.jpg');
?>
```

EDIT: you should use other fonts for languages like georgian, armenian and japanese, etc. The Arimo-Arial-Font only contains Latin and Russian characters.

[Japanese Fonts](http://www.freejapanesefont.com/)

[Georgian Fonts](http://fonts.ge/en/)

[Armenian Fonts](http://www.nayiri.com/tools?l=en&n=4)

ps. Sorry if my english is bad

Comment: Hello Hoog3059, I youd like to say big thanks to you it worked perfectly. Just using the right font:)