# Using php imagettftext with Wingdings font results in only boxes being displayed

Tags: php, fonts, drawing, text-rendering, imagettftext

In my php application I am using imagettftext() successfully with several font including OCR-A and others, but when I use wingding.ttf as the font I only get squares (character not found) as the result eg:imagettftext($image, 8, 0, 0, 10, 1, $font, 'ê'); to display the bold arrow down image.

Is Wingdings only for Windows OS?

Thanks.

Comment: The `ê` symbol is `0xEA` in Unicode, which according to [this](https://www.alanwood.net/demos/wingdings.html) is "Wide-headed downwards heavy barb arrow" - can you confirm that's the symbol you want to render?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Wingdings shouldn't be OS-specific, it is just a TTF file. You've copied that to the machine you are trying this on?

Comment: Yes, in the same place as the arial, ocr-a, and other font files im using.

Comment: There are some questions already about dealing with characters outside of the ISO-8859-1 charset, https://stackoverflow.com/q/9458317/1427878 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/198007/1427878 for example - see if any of the suggestions made in there help.