# PHP imagettftext() cannot display Unicode Plane 1 characters

Tags: php, unicode, imagettftext

I'm trying to render Egyptian Hyeroglyphs from Unicode Plane 1 (U+13000..U+1342F) as images with PHP `imagettftext()`

Here is my code:

```
$img = imagecreatetruecolor(240, 240);
imagettftext($img, 60, 0, 48, 192, 0, '/path/to/fonts/NotoSansEgyptianHieroglyphs-Regular.ttf', '&#78143;');`
```

NB: This Noto font correctly handles Hieroglyphs such as  `&#78143;` see [here](https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Sans+Egyptian+Hieroglyphs/tester)

[This question struggles with UTF-8 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458317/working-with-gd-imagettftext-and-utf-8-characters), but I've tested this code successfully on many fonts with many codepoints. Characters are already html entities encoded with &#...; as stated in the documentation and UTF-8 characters (accents, etc.) work fine, at least, according to my tests, up to 65533 (plane 0), but Hieroglyphs are in plane 1 and it seems to be impossible to render anything but a single blank square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It is not currently possible.** libgd does not support Unicode plane 1 characters. It's a known issue since, at least 2015, see https://github.com/libgd/libgd/issues/185