# PHP - Convert hex character to HTML entity

Tags: php, imagettftext

I'm using imagettftext to create images of certain text characters. To do this, I need to convert an array of hexidecimal character codes to their HTML equivalents and I can't seem to find any functionality built-in to PHP to do this. What am I missing? (through searching, I came across this: [PHP function imagettftext() and unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198007/php-function-imagettftext-and-unicode), but it none of the answers seem to do what I need - some characters convert but most don't).

Here's the resulting HTML representation (in the browser)

```
 [characters] => Array
    (
        [33] => A
        [34] => B
        [35] => C
        [36] => D
        [37] => E
        [38] => F
        [39] => G
        [40] => H
        [41] => I
        [42] => J
        [43] => K
        [44] => L
    )
```

Which comes from this array (not capable of rendering in imagettftext):

```
 [characters] => Array
    (
        [33] => &#x41
        [34] => &#x42
        [35] => &#x43
        [36] => &#x44
        [37] => &#x45
        [38] => &#x46
        [39] => &#x47
        [40] => &#x48
        [41] => &#x49
        [42] => &#x4a
        [43] => &#x4b
        [44] => &#x4c
    )
```

Comment: You could use [`html_entity_decode()`](http://php.net/html_entity_decode) if you had proper HTML escapes like `&#x41;` instead of just `&#x41`, but a custom `preg_replace`(_callback) would work as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [a sample](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php#47371) from the PHP manual, you could do this with a regex:

```
$newText = preg_replace('/&#x([a-f0-9]+)/mei', 'chr(0x\\1)', $oldText);
```

I'm not sure a raw `html_entity_decode()` would work in your case, as your array elements are missing the trailing `;` -- a necessary part of these entities.

**EDIT, July 2015:**

In response to Ben's comment noting the `/e` modifier being deprecated, here's how to write this using `preg_replace_callback()` and an anonymous function:

```
$newText = preg_replace_callback(
    '/&#x([a-f0-9]+)/mi', 
    function ($m) {
        return chr(hexdec($m[1]));
    },
    $oldText
);
```

Comment: It would work, I've actually tested it before posting my answer.

Comment: The /e modifier is now deprecated, use [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you obviously haven't search hard enough. **[`html_entity_decode()`](http://il.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)**.

Comment: This is the better option if you do have the trailing ; on your entities.