# Render this to image with GD

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, imagemagick, gd

I am working on a custom stole creator for a client of mine. You can see this creator at:

http://faithpointdallas.com/stoles/page/customStole

If you go create a stole with various greek letters and such you will see what a custom one could look like. Now I need to render all the greek letters and text and images to ONE SINGLE image with GD or ImageMagick. Is it possible and if so, what are your ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `imagettftext` to apply text to an image in GD ([documentation here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php)):

```
imagettftext ( resource $image , float $size , float $angle , int $x , int $y , int $color , string $fontfile , string $text )
```

Use javascript to capture the X and Y coordinates of the letters relative to the image they're sitting on top of, then send these coordinates (and the letters themselves) into the PHP script.

If you run into Unicode problems (given that you're using Greek letters) look at the selected answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198007/php-function-imagettftext-and-unicode), which should help you sort it out.