# imagettftext does not shows Russian language at all

Tags: php, utf-8, decode, utf

I am trying to print String of Russian Language in image, but it shows nothing, in this example, only 123 english is shown,здрасти is just empty space

```
$font = "Font.ttf";
                            $string = "здрасти 123 english";
            // I have tried this
                  $string = html_entity_decode($string, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');

                            imagettftext($this->fond,  20, 0, 11, 21, $textcolor, $font, $string)

;
```

I  have tried a lot of stuff but no works... Have you guys any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You 'have tried a lot of stuff' what stuff then?

did you put `charset="utf8"` in your `<head>`?

or put in `ISO-8859-5` in your charset, it's for cyrillic

http://htmlbook.ru/html/meta/charset

Or perhaps your font doesn't contain cyrillic characters? Also would be nice to see the complete code.

Comment: My generating image link :  [link])http://myapps123.com/resimg.php?r=248&u=1227885147241860&f=1721684014739808&fn=Mariam&un=Grigol) 

in that link, is only PNG so I don't know how to make their Head's for charset.  I did 
   header("Content-type: image/png; charset='utf-8'");

And in actually only resimg.php I wrote charset= "utf-8" in heads but no changes

Comment: I've Russian FOnt taken so I think it should wok, help me with this header stuff, I generate only PNG on link that I sent you so how can I write head tags there

Comment: ah, now I know what you mean: could be a possible dublicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198007/php-function-imagettftext-and-unicode) it's been solved there

Comment: I tried : 
 ' $string = "здрасти сссс სსსს ssss 343243";
  $text = mb_convert_encoding($string, 'HTML-ENTITIES',"UTF-8");
// Convert HTML entities into ISO-8859-1
$text = html_entity_decode($string,ENT_NOQUOTES, "ISO-8859-1");
// Convert characters > 127 into their hexidecimal equivalents
$out = "";
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($text); $i++) {
    $letter = $text[$i];
    $num = ord($letter);
    if($num>127) {
      $out .= "&#$num;";
    } else {
      $out .=  $letter;
    }
} '
But nothings shows now, even not English anguage

Comment: And wrote $out in imagettftext instead of  $string

Comment: ' $text = "здрасти сссс სსსს ssss 343243";
$text = mb_convert_encoding($text, 'HTML-ENTITIES',"UTF-8");
$text = html_entity_decode($text,ENT_NOQUOTES, "ISO-8859-1");
// Convert characters > 127 into their hexidecimal equivalents
$out = "";
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($text); $i++) {
    $letter = $text[$i];
    $num = ord($letter);
    if($num>127) {
      $out .= "&#$num;";
    } else {
      $out .=  $letter;
    }
}

 imagettftext($this->fond,  20, 0, 11, 21, $textcolor, $font, $out);'

Comment: It was problam of TTF that I used ,  download correct one, on Localhost, it works! But on website, i get Boxes when I type letter only, numbers works

Comment: good to hear. did you put the iso number inside the html entity function?

Comment: It was jutt TTF issue somehow