# How can I put an & (ampersand) on a graphical heart using imagettftext in PHP

Tags: php, imagettftext

I am creating little script to place text on graphical valentines day heart so I need the & symbol to display.  IE.  Cat & Dog
I have tried a few fonts but none will print the & using imagettftext. It just prints blank when user enters &.

Fields are entered in simple Form with text fields and posted to script, then read in script using $_POST.

Can you help?

Comment: & is a pretty normal ASCII character, there's little reason it shouldn't show up. Give us more information and code.

Comment: You don't say which fonts you're using - are they particularly obscure? Do they definitely contain that character?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198007/php-function-imagettftext-and-unicode